# Error while installing jdk in CentOS

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos, java-8, centos5

While installing JDK 1.8 in CentOS I am receiving below error.

My installation for `jdk` command is:

```
rpm -ivh <jdk name>
```

The error that i have been receiving during this particular installation is :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So believing that libgcc be missing, I executed the below command:

```
yum install libgcc
```

and encountered the below response:

```
Package libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Nothing to do

So I am stuck here now. I cannot install `jdk` because of `libgcc` issue and can't install `libgcc` because it already exist.

Please let me know if you got any options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you(the **current user**) have read **access** to the file libgcc_s.so.1

If you don't have, you can **give permissions** by using `chmod` and `chown` commands.

For example,

```
sudo chown -R <username> <path/to/libgcc_s.so.1>
```

Refer this [link](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-manage-file-and-folder-permissions-linux) for more details & examples.